# How I can make many loops into one loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code

```
word = ["General William Shelton, said the system",
        "which will provide more precise positional data",
        "and that newer technology will provide more",
        "Commander of the Air Force Space Command",
        "objects and would become the most accurate metadata"]

matched_word = ["will", "and", "in", "the", "a", "A"]
```

I have tried this code:

```
print word[0]
for item in matched_word:
        print item,":",word[0].count(item)

print word[1]
for item in matched_word:
        print item,":",word[1].count(item)

print word[2]
for item in matched_word:
        print item,":",word[2].count(item)

print word[3]
for item in matched_word:
        print item,":",word[3].count(item)
```

I get the output that I want but i dont how to create one loop for all this loop.
thank you

the output should be like this:

```
General William Shelton, said the system  
will : 0  
and : 0  
in : 0 
the :1 
a : 3  
A : 0  
which will provide more precise positional data 
will : !
and : 0  
in : 0  
the : 0  
a : 3  
A : 0
```

...and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an *outer* loop:

```
for w in word:
    print w
    for item in matched_word:
        print item, ":" ,w.count(item)
```

Comment: This will print out the item and count. What about the each array?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: the output shuold be like this:
General William Shelton, said the system
will : 0
and : 0
in : 0
the : 1
a : 3
A : 0
which will provide more precise positional data
will : 1
and : 0
in : 0
the : 0
a : 3
A : 0
and that newer technology will provide more
will : 1
and : 1
in : 0
the : 0
a : 2
A : 0
Commander of the Air Force Space Command
will : 0
and : 2
in : 0
the : 1
a : 3
A : 1
will : 0
and : 0
in : 0
the : 0
a : 3
A : 0

Comment: Right, add a print in the loop then.

Comment: i want output which is same in the question

Comment: Yes, I saw. I added a `print w` in the loop for you.

Comment: Read the post I linked to; you can mark an answer as 'accepted' by checking the green `V` below the voting score. :-)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be

```
import itertools
for w, item in itertools.product(word, matched_word):
    print item, ":", w.count(item)
```

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) gives you all possible combinations of the given iterables.

This solution doesn't work well if you need the newly-discussed `print w`. In this case, this solution is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to nested list comprehension

```
counts = [(w, i, w.count(i)) for w in word for i in matched_word]
```

you will take an array like this

```
[('General William Shelton, said the system', 'will', 0),
('General William Shelton, said the system', 'and', 0),
('General William Shelton, said the system', 'in', 0),
('General William Shelton, said the system', 'the', 1),
('General William Shelton, said the system', 'a', 3),
('General William Shelton, said the system', 'A', 0),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'will', 1),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'and', 0),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'in', 0),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'the', 0),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'a', 3),
('which will provide more precise positional data', 'A', 0),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'will', 1),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'and', 1),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'in', 0),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'the', 0),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'a', 2),
('and that newer technology will provide more', 'A', 0),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'will', 0),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'and', 2),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'in', 0),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'the', 1),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'a', 3),
('Commander of the Air Force Space Command', 'A', 1),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'will', 0),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'and', 1),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'in', 0),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'the', 1),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'a', 6),
('objects and would become the most accurate metadata', 'A', 0)]
```

then you can use `groupby` from `itertools`

```
groupped = groupby(counts, lambda i: i[0])
```

and finally

```
for category, items in groupped:
    print category, '\n', "\n".join([":".join(map(str, j[1:])) for j in list(items)])
```